# Performing similar analysis on multiple dataframes

Tags: python

I am reading data from multiple dataframes.
Since the indexing and inputs are different, I need to repeat the pairing and analysis. I need dataframe specific outputs. This pushes me to copy paste and repeat the code.

Is there a fast way to refer to multiple dataframes to do the same analysis?

````
DF1= pd.read_csv('DF1 Price.csv')
DF2= pd.read_csv('DF2 Price.csv')
DF3= pd.read_csv('DF3 Price.csv') # These CSV's contain main prices

DF1['ParentPrice']   = FamPrices ['Price1'] # These CSV's contain second prices
DF2['ParentPrice']   = FamPrices ['Price2']
DF3['ParentPrice']   = FamPrices ['Price3']

DF1['Difference'] = DF1['ParentPrice'] - DF1['Price'] # Price difference is the output
DF2['Difference'] = DF2['ParentPrice'] - DF2['Price']
DF3['Difference'] = DF3['ParentPrice'] - DF3['Price']```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to parametrize strings using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), available in python >= 3.6. In an f string, it is possible to insert the string representation of the value of a variable inside the string, as in:

```
>> a=3
>> s=f"{a} is larger than 11"
>> print(s)
3 is larger than 1!
```

Your code would become:

```
list_of_DF = []
for symbol in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    df = pd.read_csv(f"DF{symbol} Price.csv")
    df['ParentPrice']   = FamPrices [f'Price{symbol}']
    df['Difference'] = df['ParentPrice'] - df['Price'] 
    list_of_DF.append(df)
```

then DF1 would be list_of_DF[0] and so on.

As I mentioned, this answer is only valid if you are using python 3.6 or later.

Comment: Hi, if you believe this (or any other) to be the best answer to your problem, as the asker you may [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

for the third part ill suggest to create a something like

```
DFS=[DF1,DF2,DF3]
def create_difference(dataframe):
    dataframe['Difference'] = dataframe['ParentPrice'] - dataframe['Price']
for dataframe in DFS:
    create_difference(dataframe)
```

for the second way there is no like superconvenient and short way i might think about , except maybe of

```
for i in range len(DFS) :
    DFS[i]['ParentPrice'] = FamPrices [f'Price{i}']
```